# Why doesn't reference loop detection use reference equality?

Tags: c#, json.net

When serializing the object below, Json.Net detects a self-referencing loop and throws an exception.

The class has two important features:

- it has a self-referential property, `Child`
- it overrides `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Foo Child { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => (obj as Foo).Value == this.Value;

    public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();
}

...

var foo = new Foo { Value = 42, Child = new Foo { Value = 42 } };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo); // Throws JsonSerializationException
```

It appears that Json.Net uses the override of `Equals()` to detect the reference loop (confirmed by debugging). But there is no loop here.

**Why doesn't it use *reference* equality to check for a reference loop?**

I found [a test](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Serialization/ReferenceLoopHandlingTests.cs#L271) demonstrating that one can supply a different `EqualityComparer` which does use reference equality, but I'm interested to know why that isn't the default behaviour.

Comment: It does.  By default `Object.Equals(...)` checks for reference equality for referential types.  You have overridden it to not do this.  It thinks there's a loop because your equality test checks for value equality based on a single property.  Why is this surprising?

Comment: Hi @Amy, I would say that the point of overriding `Equals()` is to check for *logical* equality. My suggestion here is that, for the purpose of detecting a *reference* loop, Json.Net should not care about logical equality, only reference equality.

Comment: I was answering your question.  You asked why it doesn't.  It does.  You explicitly told it not to.  Don't expect referential equality when you specifically check for value equality.

Comment: You should *never* use a mutable value in `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: Hi @itsme86, thanks for the advice. I will update my production version of the `Foo` class accordingly ;)

Comment: To expand on @itsme86's point, the documentation for `Object.Equals` says: "You should not override Equals on a mutable reference type. This is because overriding Equals requires that you also override the GetHashCode method, as discussed in the previous section. This means that the hash code of an instance of a mutable reference type can change during its lifetime, which can cause the object to be lost in a hash table."

Comment: @Amy I think the OP is asking why it uses `Equals` instead of using `object.ReferenceEquals`.  As in it should not blindly assume that `Equals` will do reference equality.

Comment: This question feels primarily opinion-based to me.  Anyway Newtonsoft answered your question in [Object reference equality should be used when checking for circular references #401](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/401#issuecomment-77711185):  *I prefer the current behavior which lets devs customize logic by overriding Equals.  Besides, this is a big breaking change.*

Comment: @juharr by default `Object.Equals` calls `Object.ReferenceEquals` for referential types.  For value types, `Object.Equals` checks for value equality.  Calling `Object.ReferenceEquals` directly when value types are involved will result in boxing.

Comment: Hi @dbc, thank you for addressing the question and linking to the GitHub issue, that is exactly the kind of discussion I failed to find myself. If you can be bothered to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Amy I know.  I'm saying the OP might wonder why the Json.Net code is using `Equals` instead of explicitly calling `ReferenceEquals` is all.

Comment: This question is spot on. When detecting _reference loops_, only _reference equality_ matters. Allowing users to make the comparison differently introduces nothing except potential trouble. Custom equality could fail to detect the loop. It's also very annoying when objects happen to consciously implement `Equals()` by throwing a `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newtonsoft explicitly addressed this question in *[Issue  #401: Object reference equality should be used when checking for circular references](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/401#issuecomment-77711185)*:

> I prefer the current behavior which lets devs customize logic by overriding Equals.
>
> Besides, this is a big breaking change.

But then later added:

> Added EqualityComparer to JsonSerializer [3cc797c](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/3cc797c24071b35429674205712ed0a5df8cf7ad).

This enhancement added support for [`JsonSerializerSettings.EqualityComparer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_EqualityComparer.htm) which allows the default behavior of calling [`object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) in reference loop detection to be overridden in settings:

> `public IEqualityComparer EqualityComparer { get; set; }`
>
> Gets or sets the equality comparer used by the serializer when comparing references.