# Newtonsoft.Json - self referencing loop but DTO doesn't seem to have one

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I created a class that contained another class. Newtonsoft tells me there is a self referencing loop when JsonConvert.SerializeObject(translatedResponse) is called on the object. After trying various things, I changed the namespace name (which was 'DocumentGenerationParticipant', and created a DocumentGenerationParticipantResult for the plural class's List, instead of using the singular version that is also a DTO for a /participant endpoint. That worked, but I don't see why JSON serialization wouldn't work on this, and I see no circular reference? Did I miss something?

Program.CS that uses below DTOs:

```
using ConsoleApp4.DocumentGeneration;
using ConsoleApp4.DocumentGeneration.DocumentGenerationParticipant;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse>()
            {
                new DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse("testName","testEmail","testUri","testRole"),
                new DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse("testName","testEmail","testUri","testRole"),
                new DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse("testName","testEmail","testUri","testRole")
            };
            var response = new DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse(list);
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp4.DocumentGeneration
{
    public class DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public string Email { get; }

        public string AccessUri { get; }

        public string Role { get; }

        public DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse(string name, string email, string accessUri, string role)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Email = email;
            this.AccessUri = accessUri;
            this.Role = role;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse tmp = (DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse)obj;
            return Equals(this.Name, tmp.Name) &&
                   Equals(this.Email, tmp.Email) &&
                   Equals(this.AccessUri, tmp.AccessUri) &&
                   Equals(this.Role, tmp.Role);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = -2099;
                hashCode = hashCode * -2399 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Name);
                hashCode = hashCode * -2399 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Email);
                hashCode = hashCode * -2399 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(AccessUri);
                hashCode = hashCode * -2399 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Role);
                return hashCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4.DocumentGeneration.DocumentGenerationParticipant
{
    public class DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse
    {
        public List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse> Participants { get; }

        public DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse(List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse> participants)
        {
            Participants = participants;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!(obj is List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse> list))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (list.Count != this.Participants.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Participants.SequenceEqual(list);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = -2099;
                this.Participants.ForEach(x => hashCode = hashCode * x.GetHashCode());
                return hashCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Error Message:    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Participants' with type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XXXXXX.Api.Management.Contracts.DocumentGeneration.DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse]'.
>   Path ''.",

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: repeated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type

Comment: I'll add something to make it verifiable.

It's not a repeat of the listed question as that question doesn't ask *where* the circular reference is it seems to suggest fixing ones that exist.

Comment: You override `Equals()` which is what the reference loop detection uses to check for circular references.  See [Why doesn't reference loop detection use reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46936395).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you overrode `DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse.Equals(object obj)` to make an object of type `DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse` **equal to one of its own properties**:

```
public class DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse
{
    public List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse> Participants { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(obj is List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse> list))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (list.Count != this.Participants.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Participants.SequenceEqual(list);
    }

    // Remainder snipped
```

Specifically it will be equal to **any `List<DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse>` with the same contents as its own `Participants` list.**  This explains the exception you are seeing.  As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938352/3744182) to *[Why doesn't reference loop detection use reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46936395/3744182)*, Json.NET uses object equality rather than reference equality in checking for circular references.  Thus, when serializing the `Participants` property, Json.NET thinks it is equal to the parent `DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse`, and throws the exception you are seeing.

If you don't want to use object equality when checking for circular references, you can override  [`JsonSerializerSettings.EqualityComparer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_EqualityComparer.htm) and replace the default behavior of calling [`object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) in reference loop detection with something else, e.g. `ReferenceEqualityComparer` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520207) to *[IEqualityComparer<T> that uses ReferenceEquals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890058)* by [AnorZaken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533837/anorzaken).  But before doing that, you should examine your `Equals()` methods to make sure they are really doing what you want, since in this case `DocumentGenerationParticipantsResponse.Equals()` looks broken as the equality method is returning `true` for objects of different type.

(And, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393666/3744182) by [Daniel Gimenez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2497335/daniel-gimenez), `DocumentGenerationParticipantResponse.Equals()` also looks broken.  Among other issues it does not check for the incoming `object obj` being of the correct type.)

Further reading:

- *[How to best implement Equals for custom types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/567642/344280)*
- [*Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed up up the Equals and it runs fine. That seems to be root cause of the issue, the broken Equals override. With those fixed up, I can write out the serialized output. Accepted answer.